# connecting DB Mysql with android app using JSON & php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I'm connecting to external database from my android application using PHP & JSON.
it's a simple login system , it vérify if the username and password exist on the DB so it go to the Main2activity but if diffrent user and pass it show a error message
 I am successfully connected to database and getting results in browser,but while coming to android i'm not getting any results it is showing : 
Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.
 **Below is my code:**

***MainActivity.java :***

```
package com.example.hussienalrubaye.mysqlsystemlogin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void bulogin(View view) {
   //get user name and password
        EditText txtusername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        EditText txtpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
        new MyAsyncTaskresources().execute("http://l3pfe.byethost33.com/db.php?username="+txtusername.getText().toString()+"&password=" +txtpassword.getText().toString());
    }


    String result = "";
    public class MyAsyncTaskresources extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }
        @Override
        protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {


            InputStream isr = null;

            try{
 String URL=params[0];
                URL url = new URL( URL);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                isr  = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            }

            catch(Exception e){

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());



            }

//convert response to string

            try{

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                }

                isr.close();

                result=sb.toString();

            }

            catch(Exception e){

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());

            }

//parse json data


            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String  result2){
            try {

                String s = "";

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    s = s + "login info : " + json.getString("id") + " " + json.getString("username") + " " + json.getString("password");
                break;}
                if(s.length()>0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(in);}
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"user name or password isnot correct",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } catch (Exception e) {

// TODO: handle exception

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());

            }
        }




    }
}
```

***Main2Activity.java :***

```
package com.example.hussienalrubaye.mysqlsystemlogin;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

***activity_main.xml :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:hint="Enter user name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/etusername" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:hint="Enter password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etpassword" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:onClick="bulogin" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

***activity_main2.xml :***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.hussienalrubaye.mysqlsystemlogin.Main2Activity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main2" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
***content_main2.xml :***
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main2"
    tools:context="com.example.hussienalrubaye.mysqlsystemlogin.Main2Activity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my control pannel"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

***db.php :***

```
    <?php

mysql_connect("sql306.byethost33.com","b33_19513012","loool");//change server name  //pass username according your settings

mysql_select_db("b33_19513012_pfe");// also chang the Mysql database name


$sql1=mysql_query("select * from admins WHERE username ='" . $_GET['username'] . "' and password='" . $_GET['password'] ."'"); //querstirng

if (!$sql1) {

echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();

exit;

}

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))

$output[]=$row;



print(json_encode($output));// this will print the output in json

mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firt of all I'd like to warn you that mysql_connect is already deprecated, there is no mysql_connect anymore with PHP 7. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php) instead.

As the [mysql_connect doc](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php) says, you should specify the connection link. Check the `$link` variable.

```
$link = mysql_connect("sql306.byethost33.com", "b33_19513012", "loool");//change server name  //pass username according your settings
mysql_select_db("b33_19513012_pfe", $link);// also chang the Mysql database name
$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from admins WHERE username ='" . $_GET['username'] . "' and password='" . $_GET['password'] . "'", $link); //querstirng

if (!$sql1) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error($link);
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}
print(json_encode($output));// this will print the output in json

mysql_close($link);
```

Good luck!